# add data in the header dynamically

Tags: asp.net

I have a grid in which in creating a header dynamically, it contains total,
I'm getting the total from the query and storing it in the hidden field, but value is stored in the

```
(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
```

but the header is getting created in

```
(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
```

how to assign the value in the header text

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
 {
    for (int i = StartNum; i <= EndNum; i++)
    {
       e.Row.Cells[j + 1].Text = "Week No : " + i.ToString();
       j++;
     }
  }
```

Comment: thanks for the reply can you please help me with the code how will it read the value from the data set

Comment: the exact case: I'm retrieving the value using the query and putting it in the dataset. Then onRowCreated event, I'm creating the dynamic header. The header contains two columns one is text and another one is showing the total which is coming from the query i need to show the total on that field.    how will i use this code there please help

Comment: solved it: saved the data in the hidden field before binding the grid